what is this box and how can I remove it?
I have this really annoying beige bar at the top of 4 or 5 different reports in Looker. This is visible to all editors while in edit mode. It also seems to prevent me from scrolling fully to the bottom of a report page.
What is this thing? Why can't I remove it? why is it not showing up in all of my reports?
upper right of edit interface showing the beige bar in context
I have tried closing the report and reopening it. I have asked others to see if they are able to see the same thing - they see the same as I do.
I have adjusted all the page settings that I can find. The only thing I can see that makes any change at all is that when I check the Margins box, it changes from beige to white.
I'm really frustrated that I am losing about an inch of space to visualize things and can only see the bottom of the page if I make the page longer.

upon further research - this is only visible in reports with multiple pages. All of my reports with only one page are unaffected.

If possible share one dummy report here replicating this issue so that we can check it out directly. the screenshot is not of much help!
